# How to prove a series doesn't converge in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\langle x \rangle$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose a seires $A=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+px)^i$ and I was trying to prove it doesn't converge in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\langle x \rangle$. Is it correct to say that because we know that $|1+px|_{p}=1$, it cannot converge w.r.t the p-adic norm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, since in $\;p\,-$ adic analysis convergence of series is pretty simple: a series $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges iff $\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$, and this isn't fulfilled here by what you wrote.

I never saw the notation $\;\Bbb Z_p\langle x\rangle\;$ , which apparently means ring of power series, which I know by $\;\Bbb Z_p[[x]]\;$ .

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle x\rangle$ is the `Tate algebra'--the ring of convergent (on the closed unit ball of $\mathbb{C}_p$ say) power series.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I've seen, though not studied deeply **at all**, Tate algebras before. Never saw this notation, though. For example, check here http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/aws.pdf or also here http://www.mat.uc.cl//~rmenares/TateAlgebras.pdf . Anyway, the series convergence fact remains. Thanks.

Comment: I'm very well versed in Tate algebras. Thanks for the references regardless though :P